# Large Object Replication using AWS DMS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, dms, pglogical

Wanted to check if Large Object replication is supported by AWS DMS when Source and destination DB's are PostgreSQL?

I just used **pglogical** to replicate a DB which has Large Object (Like IOD's etc) and the target DB does not have LO's.

When I query a table on the destination which uses a OID column:

```
select id, lo_get(json) from table_1 where id=998877;
ERROR:  large object 6698726 does not exist
```

**The json column is oid datatype**

If AWS DMS takes care of it, I will start using it.

Thanks

Comment: Avoid large objects if you can, they may give you trouble.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe -- Thanks for the reply but is there a way to replicate LO's in Postgres?

Comment: In PostgreSQL yes, but you are asking about Amazon AWS, so I can't tell (closed source).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe -- Can you tell me how do take care of LO replication within PostgreSQL or do I create a new post for it?

Comment: In PostgreSQL, you'd use streaming replication. Nothing else will replicate large objects.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe -- Thanks for the reply. Here is my requirement - Source DB Instance has more than 5 DB's on it. I am migrating one DB out of those 5. From this DB, I need to filter rows and then migrate a subset of the data to the target DB. The data to be migrated involved tables which use Large Objects. I tested with PgLogical but LO's were not migrated and thats why I thought of DMS. Any suggestions?

Comment: As I said, no suggestions, because I don't know the capabilities of Amazon AWS.